# Multiply block matrix with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider the following block matrix:
$$
\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}B & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ AB & B & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ A^{N-1}B & A^{N-2}B & \dots & B\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $(0,AB,B)\in\mathbb{C}^{1000\times144}$

Now I want to perform a simple operation like this
$$
\tilde{\Phi} = \begin{bmatrix}CB & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ CAB & CB & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ CA^{N-1}B & CA^{N-2}B & \dots & CB\end{bmatrix}
$$
So basically I want to multiply every submatrix in the block matrix with $C$. Is there any known operator that does this? I have searched the internet for Kronecker, Hadamard, Khatri-Rao, etc multiplications but I cannot find the correct operator. I have to do this kind of multiplication for a number of matrices, and it is cumbersome to write this out every single time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $C\mkern1mu$? Also, you multiply each block by $C$, except the block in the second row, second column? Last: do all blocks have the same size?

Comment: Err sorry that is just sloppy writing, i multiply each block with $C\in\mathbb{R}^{10\times 1000}$.

Comment: Are we to deduce from your comment that the matrix $A$ is square? As far as I can see what you are considering is the product of three terms: first is $C\otimes I_N$, third is $B\otimes I_N$, middle one is something like $I\otimes I+A\otimes X+A^2\otimes X^2+\dots$ where $X$ is the canonical nilpotent matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by multiplying the original matrix with $I \otimes C$ from the left.